# To SELECT TO_CHAR (300000000000, '999G999G999D99') FROM DUAL;

Tags: sql

When I running the query the SQL execution is returning ############### as output

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (300000000000, '999G999G999D99') FROM DUAL;
```

why am I getting ###############?

Comment: `DUAL` is an Oracle thing. Either remove `postgresql` and replace with `oracle` tag or supply a Postgres query.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It is not prohibited to `create table dual as select 'X' as dummy` in postgres to "reuse" Oracle code. But the above code is showind hash signs (if you remove `dual` or create it upfront).

Comment: @astentx, then that should be mentioned in the question as it affects what `to_char()`  is being used.

Comment: To be honest, in PG it returns hashes with group separators, but entire string of hashes is really in Oracle.

Comment: Try `SELECT TO_CHAR (300000000000, '999G999G999G999D99') ;` You do not have enough `9`'s in your template to cover the size of the input number.

Comment: From [the dosc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C): *All number format models cause the number to be rounded to the specified number of significant digits. If a value has more significant digits to the left of the decimal place than are specified in the format, **then pound signs (#) replace the value***. For Postgres I failed to find this in the docs, but it works the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why am I getting ###############?

Because you've asked oracle to format a 12 digit number but allowed it only 9 digits to do it with:

[image]

Either make the number 3 digits shorter, or make the format string 3 digits longer

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (300000000, '999G999G999D99') FROM DUAL;  
SELECT TO_CHAR (300000000000, '999G999G999G999D99') FROM DUAL;
```